# Do Google Chrome Extensions still support Canvas?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm overriding the new tab page and I want to get started with just a simple canvas, but my new tab page is still blank even after adding the JS code for the canvas. In the example I'm following the JS code produces a black canvas on the new tab screen.

**HTML (journal.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title> My Journal </title>
        <script src = "sketch.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>Here's The Journal</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS (sketch.js):**

```
function setup(){
    createCanvas(500,500);
    background(0);
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "MyJournal",
    "version": "0.1",

    "chrome_url_overrides" : {
        "newtab": "journal.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "JournalLogo.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: `createCanvas` isn't part the Canvas API. It appears to be part of P5? Have you included that? https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas

Comment: You're right, can't believe I forgot that thanks so much